# I want to Serve React App with react router dom with echo

Tags: reactjs, go, react-router-dom, go-echo

I want to Serve React App with react router dom with echo in Go. But I'm facing a problem in routing because if I directly go to that route I get not found error

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    checkerror "server/checkError"
    connectdb "server/connectDB"
    "server/handler"

    "github.com/gofor-little/env"
    echo "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    err := env.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    userDB := connectdb.UserDB{Name: "Hi", DBP: nil}
    err = userDB.ConnectDB()
    fmt.Println(userDB.DBP)
    checkerror.Checkerror(err)
    e := echo.New()
    e.Static("/","build")
    e.Use(middleware.Logger())
    handler.Apihandler(e, userDB.DBP)
    e.File("/","index.html")
    
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
    
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("DB disconnected")
        userDB.CloseDB()
    }()
}
```

This is code to serve the app
Please help

I want to get access of routes from react

Comment: See if anything from the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) is helpful for your specific use case. Basic gist is that the root index.html file should be returned for all page requests into the app. Just a complete shot in the dark, maybe `e.File("/", "index.html")` should be something like `e.File("/*", "index.html")` or `e.File("*", "index.html")`?

Comment: I tried that then it's just showing blank page

Comment: Ah bummer, thought it was worth a shot. Hopefully someone versed in Go/echo comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of serving static files using static use the middleware of StaticWith config so it can redirect to index.HTML if route is not found

```
e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
    Skipper: nil,
    // Root directory from where the static content is served.
    Root: "build",
    // Index file for serving a directory.
    // Optional. Default value "index.html".
    Index: "index.html",
    // Enable HTML5 mode by forwarding all not-found requests to root so that
    // SPA (single-page application) can handle the routing.
    HTML5:      true,
    Browse:     false,
    IgnoreBase: false,
    Filesystem: nil,
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer. When `e.Static` serves files directly, echo mux intercepts the routes and rejects them. Hence you see the 'Not found' error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35713171)